# Mapping and obstacle avoidance with Hokuyo Laser Scanner

Tags: navigation, rviz, laser, hokuyo, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone!

I would like to use my Hokuyo Laser Scanner to implement mapping and obstacle avoidance capabilities. Can anybody guide me with the steps?

Currently, I am only able to view the laser scan in RVIZ after going through the Hokuyo_node tutorials.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62043/mapping-and-obstacle-avoidance-with-hokuyo-laser-scanner/) by [Edward Ramsay](https://answers.ros.org/users/4814/edward-ramsay/) on ROS Answers with karma: 65 on 2013-05-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use the [navigation stack](http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation) with [gmapping](http://www.ros.org/wiki/gmapping) or [hector](http://www.ros.org/wiki/hector_slam) for SLAM.

---

Originally posted by [Jbot](https://answers.ros.org/users/1000/jbot/) with karma: 429 on 2013-05-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2